# Add multipe time delays in python

Tags: python

Hello here is a copy of my code i have been writing.
https://github.com/Octane70/Code/blob/master/Garden/Garden_v0.1.py

The problem I am having is that my DHT temprature and moisture sensor will no refresh as fast as the time and moisture which is sleep(1). I would like to add a different sleep time of about sleep(120), but i have came to a dead end on my searching. if anyone has any suggestions or a tutorial they could point me to would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how much delay you want to put.... What do you mean by "about sleep(120)"?

Comment: Basically I would like the time and moisture sensor to refresh at a different time then the DHT temperature, humidity sensor. So I would like to keep the sleep(1) for the time and moisture sensor and sleep(120) for the DHT sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's still a gap between my understanding and your expected effect. Since from your code you only read humidity and temperature once. I'll propose something like this. Keep a `sleep(1)` in the while loop, but use a counter to decide it's time to read from different sensors. My partial code will be:

```
counter = 0

while True:
    if counter % 120 == 0:
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(22, 4)
    moisture = ReadChannel(2)

    # then following lcd stuff, lcd.clear() and lcd message()...

    counter += 1
    sleep(1)
```